# How can I set the output file for Perl's File::Fetch?

Tags: perl

I am using [File::Fetch](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Fetch.html) in a Perl script. How can I get File::Fetch to store a file to be downloaded in a specified file?

I have tried:

```
    use File::Fetch;
    my $ff = File::Fetch->new(uri => 'http://stackoverflow.com/users/63550');
    #my $where = $ff->fetch() or die $ff->error; # Creates a file named "63550".
    my $where = $ff->fetch(to => 'SO.html'); # Creates a subfolder named SO.html with a file named "63550" in it.
```

A workaround would be to rename the file after download, but is it possible to specify the file name immediately?

Test platform:

- ActiveState Perl 64 bit. From `perl -v`:

  ```
  v5.10.0 built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
  Binary build 1004 [287188] provided by ActiveState.
  ```
- Windows XP.

Comment: The workaround is to use `$ff->output_file` to get the actual output file name (for instance, a URL with a "?" would not be reflected in the output file name) and then rename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code, the only way seems to be making a subclass and overriding the `output_file` method. I guess the author would accept a patch that makes `output_file` a read/write property, so that it can be changed at run-time.

Comment: Which routine specifically? There are only two uses of the method. One of them uses it to construct the final path (it has no impact on the original URL), the other one uses it as the target file name for the FTP GET command (also, no impact on the original URL). Making output_file return something that is not derived from file is just fine.

Comment: Well, you are wrong. `_lwp_fetch` runs `$ua->mirror($uri, $to)` and guess where `$to` comes from? :)

Comment: File::Fetch has a subclass bug that prevents this from working (really, please try what you suggest before you suggest it). I've filed the bug as https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=53427

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the [File::Fetch](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Fetch) 0.22 code to see what you would need to do for this. There's a bug that prevents you from subclassing (unless you want to override `new()` and `create()` to fix it). *Update* The `File::Fetch` developers have applied my patch and a new release should be out shortly.

The easiest thing is probably to fetch the file to a temporary directory, discover the name with `output_file`, and [rename](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) it to its final location.

Lukáš thinks I'm wrong, but I don't think he's actually tried it like I had. Creating a subclass and overriding `output_file` has no effect:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN {
package File::Fetch::MyOutput;
use parent qw(File::Fetch);

sub output_file { die "I was called!" }
}

my $ff = File::Fetch::MyOutput->new( 
     uri => 'http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/File-Fetch-0.22/lib/File/Fetch.pm' 
     );

$ff->fetch( to => '.' );
```

When I run this, I end up with *Fetch.pm* in the current directory. The script does not die because it never invoked my `output_file` because the object is not actually in my subclass. This is a bug in `File::Fetch` which I've filed as [RT 53427](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=53427).

Comment: File::Fetch has a bug in that it fails the null subclass test. It doesn't care what you do in a subclass because it will never see it unless you override new() to fix the bug. I think that's to much work.