# Perl adding date/time to a file name

Tags: perl, file, datetime

I am using the following script to download a file over http and a utility method to get the current date.

```
use File::Fetch;
use DateTime qw();

sub getDateUtility{
    return DateTime->now->strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
}

sub fetchFile{
   my $fileHandler = File::Fetch->new(uri => 'http://sample.com/file2fetch.txt');
   my $placeFile = $fileHandler->fetch() or die $fileHandler->error;
}
```

Now I want to save the file with the current date as name of the file. How can I replace the file name with the current date in above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do that. The best you can do is to make a temporary directory, fetch the file there using the default name, then rename it to the name you need. Use `File::Temp::tempdir`:

```
use File::Fetch;
use DateTime qw();
use File::Temp qw( tempdir );

sub getDateUtility {
    return DateTime->now->strftime('%m_%d_%Y')
}

sub fetchFile {
        my ($url, $destination) = @_;
        my $tempdir = tempdir( CLEANUP => 1 );
        my $fetcher = File::Fetch->new(
                uri => $url,
                to  => $tempdir,
        );
        my $fetched = $fetcher->fetch() or die $fetcher->error;
        rename($fetched, $destination);
}

fetchFile('http://ec2-54-169-147-210.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/export.php?test=141121_5N_39140a1bc54a1cf78c9b131ed52f8654', getDateUtility() . '.txt');
```

Please note that I changed your `getDateUtility` function to use underscores `_` as a separators, not slashes `/`, as you cannot use slashes in a file name.

See also: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993050/how-can-i-set-the-output-file-for-perls-filefetch).